# Can two free floating clocks synch up without a common reference?

Tags: relativity, time

If you had two clocks out it space somewhere and they could communicate by radio, would it be possible to coordinate a synchronization to the same degree as if they began their journey from the same point and time?

Comment: Ignoring gravity, if the two clocks are (uniformly) moving relative to each other, each clock will find that the other clock is running slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take from the question that these 2 clocks are *not* moving WRT each other but are merely separated by some distance. By 'synchronized' do you mean they tick at the same rate? or that they read the same time? Since they can confirm by radio that they tick at the same rate, the problem becomes getting them to read the same time. The best practice then would be to measure the time it takes to send a ping from one to the other and back, and use this to get the distance and then use this lag to get them both in synch. However this is only valid in the inertial frame they share. There is no frame-invariant definition of "remote from one another but at the same time". See 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_synchronisation

Comment: indeed the reason I asked this question was to validate the starting conditions of my own "thought experiments" that begin with two synchronized clocks not moving with WRT each other, so thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Do the clocks moving at relativistic speed one with respect to the other? I guess that this is the case, otherwise the synchronization is quite simple.

In the relativistic case the situation is complicated. The time elapsed between two events is the shortest in the frame where the events occur in the same place. Now let's denote by $A$ and $B$ the frames in which the two clocks are at rest.

Let the clock in the frame $A$ beat at a certain time $t_1$, and 12 hour later beat $t_2 = t_1 + 12$. According to the frame $B$ the two events didn't occur at the same place, s.t.  the reading of the clock in the frame $B$ shows between the two beats of the clock of $A$ more than 12h.

However, the situation is symmetrical. Let the clock of the frame $B$ beat the time $t_1$ and 12h after, the time $t_2 = t_1 + 12$. In the fame $A$ the two beats of the clock of $B$ occurred in different places, s.t. the reading of the clock of $A$ shows between those two beats of the clock in $B$ more than 12h.

No synchronization.